# Where is my mistake in my website responsiveness?

Tags: html, css, ios

I've developed a very basic calculator on a website, but for the life of me, I cannot seem to get it responsive on my iPhone (i'm running iphone 12 pro max).

I'm running google chrome. I've tried clearing cookies and cache.

I've tried using an online emulator - which shows it looking how I want it to look, but in practice, it does not come out this way.

Here's the emulated version:

[image: emulated iphone 12 pro max]

Here is the css:

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container2 {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.fflogo img {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h2 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input[type="number"],
input[type="text"] {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}

button[type="submit"] {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
  margin: center;  
}

button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.container3 {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-box {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#logo1 {
  width: 230px; /* adjust this value to change the width of the logo */
  height: auto; /* maintains aspect ratio of the logo */
}

#results {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#results p {
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#results table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#results th,
#results td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#results th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Style the header with a dark background but no padding */
.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style the header links */
.header a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px; /* Add more right padding */
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  position: relative; /* Add relative positioning */
}

/* Style the active/current link*/
.header a.active {
  background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
  color: white;
}

/* Style the button background */
.header a::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0; /* Position the background to the right */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: rgb(58, 58, 58); /* Background color for the button */
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
}

/* Style the button background on hover */
.header a:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Style the button text */
.header a span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px;

}

/* Float the link section to the right */
.header-right {
  float: right;
}

.header-right a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #282828;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-right a.active {
  background-color: #282828;
}

.header-right a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add media queries for responsiveness - when the screen is 500px wide or less, stack the links on top of each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #logo1 {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .fflogo img {
      max-width: 80%;
      height: auto;
    }
  }

/* Apply these styles to screens smaller than 600px */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 90%;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  form {
    display: block;
  }
  input[type="number"],
  input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  body {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  
  .header {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .header .logo {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .container {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  input[type="text"],
  input[type="number"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* Add bottom margin */
  }
  
  button[type="submit"] {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}


/* Apply these styles to screens larger than 600px */
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 800px;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
  form {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  input[type="number"],
  input[type="text"] {
    width: auto;
  }
}

#calculator button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Hide "Calculate" button in header on mobile devices */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header-right {
    display: none;
  }
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px; /* set a maximum width for the container */
  margin: 0 auto; /* center the container */
  padding: 0 21px; /* add padding to the container */
}

.container h1 {
  font-size: 3rem; /* set a larger font size for the heading on larger screens */
  text-align: center;
}

.container p {
  font-size: 1.2rem; /* set a larger font size for the paragraph text on larger screens */
  line-height: 1.5; /* set a line-height to improve readability */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* styles for screens smaller than 768px */
  .container {
    max-width: 90%; /* reduce the width of the container */
    padding: 0 5px; /* reduce the padding */
  }
  
  .container h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem; /* reduce the font size of the heading */
  }
  
  .container p {
    font-size: 1.1rem; /* reduce the font size of the paragraph text */
  }
}

}
```

and here is how it's currently coming out:

[image: iphone pro max 12 iphone actual with subpar code]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) Also please post more code and smaller pictures

Comment: You're likely missing the viewport meta tag in your head [@media query not working in mobile. Works fine in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344339/media-query-not-working-in-mobile-works-fine-in-chrome)